# Use SLDS Icon file path in VF page

Tags: visualforce, slds, icon

Let's say I have a markup

```
  <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon--small slds-icon-utility-edit">
    <img src="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/images/profile_avatar_96.png')}" />
 </span>
```

how can I find path for icon-utility-edit in this case?

Comment: Didn't understand your question? Can you explain it differently!!

Comment: Surely I can. So I want know file name for slds/utility/edit icon. In my case  'assets/images/profile_avatar_96.png' provides me profile icon. I want "edit" from slds. Now it's more cleared? Moreover I want know where I can find file names' for all available slds incons

Comment: Means you want to use slds icons instead of using your own png image/icon? Is that correct? And you want a library where names of all slds icons are written?

Comment: Exactly! I want to use standart slds icons and want to know from where can I get all file names for standart slds icons

Comment: Upvote & select as best answer if my answer has helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need to add lightning CSS as static resource.

Just include this tag on top of your VF page: `<apex:slds />`.

Pass the icon reference directly as shown below:

```
/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#opportunity
```

Example:

```
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#opportunity">
</use>
```

Refer this [Lightning Icons in Visualforce Page Link](https://www.biswajeetsamal.com/blog/lightning-icons-in-visualforce-page/). This will help you.

Comment: Can I really use lightning namespace in apex:page?

Comment: We are talking about "pure visual force" without  aura namespace (as You could know from my message tags)

Comment: @pincet Ohhh, you should highlight that first in question. I will check something regarding VF page. What i shared works definitely for Lightning page

Comment: My apologies, but it is all about pure VF

Comment: @pincet Check the updated answer